# How to install pyperclip to Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I want to install pyperclip from GitHub using `pip install` but unfortunately it's only installed to pip and not Anaconda. I'm using PyCharm and my interpreter is Anaconda. (Linux)

I want Anaconda to install the package 'pyperclip' as well so I can use it in PyCharm. I've try Googling but can't find any result.

Comment: use your conda-pip (use the environment in which you've installed pycharm) then it should work. But if pycharm has an internal kernel you might not use it there _if_ pycharm uses a seperate environment for the kernel.

Comment: @cricket_007 that's not "from github". It seems the development version is wanted.

Comment: By the way, `conda search pyperclip` might just show you what is available

Comment: @MSeifert True, though there are no releases "on github". The package is only located on pypi

Comment: Here's the correct link. https://anaconda.org/pypi/pyperclip

Comment: @cricket_007 You don't need to target a release, you can just `pip` install a branch. See my answer.

Comment: I'm new to python and all of this linux, anaconda thing. I have two environment setup. One is Root and another is machinelearning.  @MSeifert, I don't understand what you mean by conda-pip and conda search pyperclip only return "Fetching package metadata ......."

Answer (score 6):

From [Anaconda's website](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyperclip), run the following in Terminal/cmd:

> conda install -c conda-forge pyperclip

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the following command uses the `pip` in your `CONDA_FOLDER/Scripts/pip` or `CONDA_FOLDER/envs/ENVIRONMENT_NAME/Scripts/pip`:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip.git
```

or if a specific branch (instead of the default one is needed) then use:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip.git@BRANCHNAME
```

However you need to make sure your PyCharm actually uses the environment in which you install the package! Otherwise there is no sense in installing it in the wrong one.

Comment: If my path is : 'anaconda3/bin/python' then what command do I need to execute the installation of pyperclip to that path? 

So, now I'm getting so confuse with anaconda and python. Where does the pip install go to then if it does not go to either conda or python?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure because I am not running linux and I never tried it but according to the official website

1. run anaconda prompt
2. and then type: *conda install -c auto pyperclip=1.3*

for more info: https://anaconda.org/auto/pyperclip

Answer (score 1):

To install pyperclip from conda run following command.

```
conda install -c bryanwweber pyperclip
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a hard time installing pyperclip on Anaconda Jupyter notebook. I installed pip and also upgraded it to the latest version. I followed your answers but didn't have luck.

If you're a Windows user, here's how I resolved:

1) Open Anaconda terminal (it's your Windows terminal inside Anaconda)

2)It will open showing the C drive and your username like: `C:\Users\joe.jacob`

3)`C:\Users\joe.jacob\ dir` (this will show you where you have Jupyter Notebook. Mine was at .jupyter, so I navigated to it using: **cd .jupyter**

```
C:\Users\joe.jacob\cd .jupyter
```

4)Now install **pyperclip** at your jupyter notebook like this:

```
C:\Users\joe.jacob\.jupyter>pip install pyperclip
```

5) It installs **pyperclip** package. Installing other pip packages is similar.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

search for anaconda prompt on your computer and type one of the following

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyperclip
conda install -c "conda-forge/label/gcc7" pyperclip
conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf201901" pyperclip
conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf202003" pyperclip
```

then click enter and wait for it to download you can repeat it again to confirm whether its installed